# Close all open files handles with C#

Tags: c#, file

I have an integration/regression test suite I built on top of SpecFlow (which uses NUnit underneath).  The problem I am having is that sometimes there is an exception in a test and a file might remain open.  This is a problem in follow on tests because they cannot read/write to this file.

Is there a way to detect what files a process has open and then close them all?

Comment: Yup, you detect it by opening the file.  You'll get an IOException.  No, closing a file owned by another process is not supported, Windows honors a request to not let *anyone* mess with a file.  Stop the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should close the handles by either disposing them(best done with the `using` clause) or waiting for the finalizer. Finalizers probably won't work well for you since they might not run before the next test. So disposing them with either `try`...`finally` or `using` is the way to go.

**While you can enumerate handles and close them, you should not. Since then the handle might be closed twice, which will cause undefined behavior and crashes.**

Here is some Delphi sample code enumerating all handles of a process which you can filter down to file handles only:

```delphi
program HandleEnum;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  windows,
  SysUtils;


function EnablePrivilege(const Priv:String):boolean;
var
  rl: Cardinal;
  hToken: Cardinal;
  tkp: TOKEN_PRIVILEGES;
  p:^token_privileges;
begin
   p:=nil;
   result:=true;
   if Win32Platform <> VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT then exit;
   result:=false;
   if not OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES or TOKEN_QUERY, hToken)
     then exit;
   if not LookupPrivilegeValue(nil, Pchar(Priv), tkp.Privileges[0].Luid)
     then exit;
   tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes := SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
   tkp.PrivilegeCount := 1;
   AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, False, tkp, 0, p^, rl);
   if GetLastError <> ERROR_SUCCESS then exit;
   result:=true;
end;


const  SystemHandleInformation     = 16;
       STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH =  4;
       htProcess                   =  5;
Type _SYSTEM_HANDLE_ENTRY=packed record
  OwnerPid:Cardinal;
  ObjectType:Byte;
  HandleFlags:Byte;
  HandleValue:word;
  ObjectPointer:Pointer;
  AccessMask:Cardinal;
 end;
Type _SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION=packed record
  Count:Cardinal;
  Data:array[0..0]of _SYSTEM_HANDLE_ENTRY;
 end;
function GetProcessId(Process:Cardinal):Cardinal;stdcall;external 'Kernel32.dll';
function NtQuerySystemInformation(
  SystemInformationClass:Cardinal;
  SystemInformation:Pointer;
  SystemInformationLength:Cardinal;
  ReturnLength:PCardinal
):Cardinal;stdcall;external 'ntdll.dll';

function GetModuleFileNameExA(
  hProcess:Cardinal;
  hModule:Cardinal;
  lpFilename:PChar;
  nSize:Cardinal
):Cardinal;stdcall;external 'Psapi.dll';

function EnumProcessModules(
  hProcess:Cardinal;
  lphModule:PCardinal;
  cb:Cardinal;
  lpcbNeeded:PCardinal
):BOOL;stdcall;external 'Psapi.dll';

procedure Enum(ProcID:Cardinal=0);
var RetLength:Cardinal;
    Status:Cardinal;
    Data:^_SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION;
    i:integer;
    hProcess,hDuplicate,PID,hModule,Temp:Cardinal;
    s:String;
begin
 EnablePrivilege('SeDebugPrivilege');
  Data:=nil;
  try
    RetLength:=0;
    GetMem(Data,sizeof(_SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION));
    Status:=NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemHandleInformation, Data, sizeof(_SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION), @RetLength);
    writeln(Status);
    FreeMem(Data);
    Data:=nil;
    GetMem(Data,RetLength);
    Status:=NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemHandleInformation, Data, RetLength, @RetLength);
    if Status<>0 then Raise Exception.create('Handle enumeration: NtQuerySystemInformation returned '+inttostr(Status));
    writeln('Offset ProcID, HandleID, HandleFlags, Mask, HandleType');
    for i := 0 to Data.Count-1 do
     begin
      if data.data[i].OwnerPid<=4 then continue;//System
      SetLastError(0);
      if Data.Data[i].ObjectType<>htProcess then continue;
      hProcess := OpenProcess( PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, Data.Data[i].OwnerPid );
      //writeln(inttostr(getlasterror));
      DuplicateHandle( hProcess, Data.Data[i].HandleValue, GetCurrentProcess(), @hDuplicate, 0, FALSE, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS );
      //writeln(inttostr(getlasterror));
      PID:=GetProcessId(hDuplicate);
      //writeln(inttostr(getlasterror));
      setlength(s,1024);
      //writeln(inttostr(getlasterror));
      fillchar(S[1],length(S),0);
      EnumProcessModules( hProcess, @hModule,sizeof(hModule),@Temp);
      //writeln('B'+inttostr(getlasterror));
      SetLastError(0);
      setlength(S,GetModuleFileNameExA(hProcess,hModule,PChar(S),length(S)));
      //writeln(status);
      //writeln('A'+inttostr(getlasterror));
      closehandle(hDuplicate);
      //writeln(inttostr(getlasterror));
      closehandle(hProcess);
      if (PID<>ProcID)and(ProcID<>0) then continue;
      //writeln(inttostr(getlasterror));
      write(Data.Data[i].OwnerPid:10);
      write(Data.Data[i].HandleValue:10);
      write(Data.Data[i].HandleFlags:10);
      write(Data.Data[i].AccessMask:10);
      write(Data.Data[i].ObjectType:10);
      write(PID:10);
      writeln(S);
     end;
  finally
    FreeMem(Data);
  end;
end;

begin
  Enum(9924);
end.
```

Comment: Thanks, that's sort of what I was heading for.

Comment: The nopaste.info link is dead.

Comment: No paste link now redirects to spam site.

Comment: @LueTm I think I found the code in my archives

Answer (score 4):

You should put your files in `using` blocks so that they are closed even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: I know about using statements and I usually do use them, but there are times when using blocks don't make sense.  What do I do in those cases?

Comment: @Jeffrey: It depends on the situation.